# Multiple attachments in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, email-attachments

I'm having problems, while sending multiple attachments in my program.

I didn't have any problems before I tried to add multiple attachments.
So I changed to code a bit and it stopped working.

**Create attachment:**
Didn't add all the code to make it more viewable.

```
Attachment attachment = getAttachment(bodyFile, "Formulier" + counter + ".doc");
attachments.Add(attachment);
//attachment.Dispose();

if (attachments != null)
{
  foreach (Attachment attachment in attachments)
  {
    email.Attachments.Add(attachment);
  }
}
```

**Get Attachment**

```
private Attachment getAttachment(string bodyFile, string title)
{
  return createDocument(bodyFile, title);
}
```

**Creating file**

```
private Attachment createDocument(string bodyFile, string title) 
{
  string activeDir = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Tools");
  string newPath = Path.Combine(activeDir, "Documents");

  Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
  newPath = Path.Combine(newPath, title);

  FileStream fs = File.Create(newPath);
  fs.Close();
  File.WriteAllText(newPath, bodyFile);

  var fstemp = new FileStream(newPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
  return new Attachment(fstemp, title, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);

}
```

**The error I get in my logger**

```
2012-07-04 15:45:26,149 [19] ERROR Mvc - System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file.
   at System.IO.__Error.FileNotOpen()
   at System.IO.FileStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Mime.MimePart.Send(BaseWriter writer)
   at System.Net.Mime.MimeMultiPart.Send(BaseWriter writer)
   at System.Net.Mail.Message.Send(BaseWriter writer, Boolean sendEnvelope)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at ARTex.Tools.Mailer.Send(SmtpClient smtpClient, List`1 receivers, String subject, String body, List`1 attachments, String cc) in C:\Projects\KTN.Web.ARTex\ARTex\ARTex\Tools\Mailer.cs:line 262
```

**EDIT**

I got rid of the .Dispose method and changed `var fstemp = new FileStream(newPath ...`
Now I can send multiple attachments. But now they randomly give an error or not. 4 out of 5 times it works. 4th time it gives an error again that it can't open the file. 5th time it magicly works again.

**EDIT: Solution**

I used a using block in combination with two answers. And that worked.
Tnx to @HatSoft and @Aghilas Yakoub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with these lines (in your `CreateDocument` method):

```
var fstemp = new FileStream(newPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
return new Attachment(fstemp, title, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
```

Comment: Now I get this error when I tried what you said
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 
Failure sending mail. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file.
                at System.IO.__Error.FileNotOpen()

Comment: I think this fixed the problem. But I get random an error sometimes. But it works I guess. Thank you.

Comment: I hope I can find the new problem very quick :)

Answer (score 2):

What is line number 3 doing in code?

```
attachment.Dispose();
```

It looks like before adding it to Mail you are disposing the file.  So may be file getting closed before attachment finishes.

Comment: Thanks this was a part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the newPath in FileStream fs = File.Create(newPath); is not correct and no file gets create, looking at you code the newPath will end with 'Documents' and the File.Create file name with extension hence their wont be anything to attach.

Comment: The files do get created. The show up in my solution explorer.

Comment: Can you tell me what is inside newPath before calling FileMode.Open in FileStream please

Comment: Looks like the FileStream will also need FileAccess to Read, also please put the FileStream in a using block

Comment: The FileStream will create the right path when I debug this. I can see the files, they're created fine. But when I use them as attachment, I have to close each reader to access another file. And I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Check edit of my post. It's fixed. Also with your help. I used the using block. Thank you.